# How to apply Gronwall's inequality to get the desired claim?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, gradient-flows

Let $H\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ with $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth and suppose $H$ has a unique minimum $u_\infty\in U$. Moreoever, suppose that for some $\lambda>0$, we have that $H$ is strong convex, that is, $\nabla^2 H\geq \lambda\textbf{1}$ uniformly on $U$.

It can be shown that
$$
H[u]-H[u_\infty]\leq\frac{1}{2\lambda}D_H[u],\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
D_H[u(t)]=-\frac{d}{dt}H[u(t)]=\lVert\nabla H[u(t)]\rVert^2\geq 0.
$$

Not, it is said that from $(1)$, we can deduce by Gronwall's inequality, that
$$
e^{2\lambda t}(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])
$$
is non-increasing in time $t\geq 0$.

I am not sure if I understand the application of Gronwall's lemma.

---

Here is what I tried and think:

As far as I see, we have by (1) and the definition of $D_H[u(t)]$ that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H[u(t)]\leq -2\lambda(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])
$$

Moreoever, since $\frac{d}{dt}H[u_\infty]=\underbrace{\nabla H[u_\infty]}_{=0}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}u_\infty(t)=0$, we also can write

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(H[u(t)]+H[u_\infty])\leq -2\lambda(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]).
$$

If I set $g(t):=H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty(t)]$ and am not mistaken, Gronwall's inequality implies
$$
g(t)\leq e^{-2\lambda t}g(0)
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
e^{2\lambda t}g(t)\leq g(0)
$$

Isn't that the claim?!

PS. I am referring to [this on page 6](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekaplicky/pages/pages/2020l/matthes_entropymethods.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you have that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d t} H[u(t)] \le -2\lambda H[u(t)]+2\lambda H[u_\infty]
\end{align}
then it follows that
\begin{align}
e^{2\lambda t}\frac{d}{d t} H[u(t)] \le -2\lambda e^{2\lambda t} H[u(t)]+2\lambda e^{2\lambda t} H[u_\infty]
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d t}\left(e^{2\lambda t} \left(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]\right)\right)= e^{2\lambda t}\frac{d}{d t} H[u(t)]+2\lambda e^{2\lambda t} \left(H[u(t)]-  H[u_\infty]\right)\le 0.
\end{align}

Well, this means that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d t}F(t)\le 0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
F(t) = e^{2\lambda t} \left(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]\right).
\end{align}
Hence $F(t)$ must be non increasing since its derivative is non positive.

Although the proof of the inequality does not strictly require the use of Gronwall's lemma, it does rely on the method of integrating factor, which serves as the foundation for the proof of Gronwall's lemma.

Comment: Thank you! What do you think of my idea which I gave in my original post?

Comment: @selector I believe you only show that $e^{2\lambda t}g(t)$ is bounded. So no, it does not yield what you want.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. The reason I was confused was that the author talks about "Gronwall's inequality". So I thought that he **directly** applies this inequality and I tried to bring everything into a form which allows applying it...